# SQL cast datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, casting

In SQL Server 2005, why does:

`PRINT Cast('' AS datetime)`

display:

> Jan 1 1900 12:00AM

I would have thought it should be `null`?

Comment: ah.. time travel.. glad someone found it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty string is casted to `0` which is later casted to the era date.

Unlike `Oracle`, `SQL Server` distinguishes between `NULL` and an empty string.

Answer (score 11):

It's because empty string `''` is not `NULL`. If you do:

```
select Cast(null AS datetime)
```

OUTPUT:

```
-----------------------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

> When character data that represents
>   only date or only time components is
>   cast to the **datetime** or **smalldatetime** 
>   data types, the unspecified time
>   component is set to 00:00:00.000, and
>   the unspecified date component is set
>   to 1900-01-01.

Answer (score 1):

From experimentation, it looks like SQL Server attempts to cast directly to `DateTime`, and failing that attempts to cast to `int` and then to `DateTime`:

```
PRINT Cast('2009-1-1' AS datetime)
go
PRINT Cast('2009/1/1' AS datetime)
go
PRINT Cast('1.1' AS datetime)
go
PRINT Cast('1/2009/1' AS datetime)
go
PRINT Cast('' AS int)
go
PRINT Cast(' ' AS int)
go
PRINT Cast(0 AS datetime)
go
PRINT Cast('X' AS datetime)
go
PRINT Cast('X' AS int)
```

Output:

```
Jan  1 2009 12:00AM
Jan  1 2009 12:00AM
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Jan  1 2009 12:00AM
0
0
Jan  1 1900 12:00AM
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'X' to data type int.
```

Comment: this test shows the BOL quote from my answer in action: `select Cast('1/1/2010' AS datetime) as defaultTime,Cast('1:23:45.678' AS datetime) as defaultDate,Cast('' AS datetime) as defaultDateTime`. if time is not given it defaults to `00:00:00.000`, if date is not given it defaults to `1/1/1900`